# flask application showing 404 error for CSS file

Tags: python, css, flask

I have setup the basic components of my flash/python website and I thought I did it properly but obviously something is not right. I am using flask to serve my index.html with some css. But I keep getting this error:

```
"GET /static/stylesheets/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

This is my [Directory Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipliJ.png) image so you know how it looks like

I have put `from flask import url_for` at the top of my routes.py file

I put this in the header of index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='stylesheets/style.css') }}" />
```

This is my routes.py

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app
from flask import url_for

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

my **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask 
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import routes
```

and my index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='stylesheets/style.css') }}" />
        <title>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</h1>
    </body>

<div class="boxed">
    lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum:
    </div>


    <div class="boxed">
        this is text in a box
    </div>
</html>
```

Also, I get file not found when I go here:

```
http://localhost:5000/static/stylesheets/style.css
```

SO the webpage display but without css. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please show the rest of your code.

Comment: just added the content of __init__.py and routes.py

Comment: Can you please share your app.yaml

Comment: The static folder needs to be at the same level as the templates folder.  It's hard to tell from the dir tree image, but it looks like it is a level above.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem, I moved the static folder at the template level and it all works now.